# How to use T4 code generation templates with VS C++ projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, t4

T4 template files are automatically recognizable by the IDE under C# projects, but I have no clue on how they can be integrated into C++ projects (other than using make files).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

T4 Template files can be integrated into C++ projects, but it's a bit more work than with a C#/VB project.  Create a new text file in your C++ project and give it a .tt extension.  Then write your template as normal.  A C++ project then needs further work to get it to transform the templates. The quick and dirty way I got it to work was to add a custom build step and have it call "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.1\TextTransform.exe" directly.  Another way I found was to add a custom MSBuild task.  Instructions can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803154046/http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2008/07/25/an-msbuild-task-to-execute-t4-templates.aspx)

[This](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/t4-text-template-transformation-toolkit-code-generation-best-kept-visual-studio-secret) page has more information and some good links to other pages on using T4 code generation.

Comment: Somehow it does not seem to work. Try creating a new Win32 C++ project. Then add a simple .tt file and click build. Nothing gets generated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It can be made to work, but is definitively not as convenient as C#. Hopefully this will change in the upcoming VS 2010.

Answer (score 6):

MSBuild Task will not work as this is a vcproj file (C++) so vcbuild is used. The easiest way to get the tt compiled is to add a custom build step like below..

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.1\TextTransform.exe" -out "$(ProjectDir)\VSProject.cpp" -I "$(ProjectDir)" "$(ProjectDir)\VSProject.tt"
```

I spent several hours investigating the MSBuild Task solution above and it's pretty good for managed code but I can't see any way to use it for C++ (bar converting the vcproj to csproj eek)

Comment: Even with this solution, don't you still have to manually add the cpp file to the vcproj file?

Answer (score 5):

#### For Visual Studio 2017 (and maybe 2015?)

The commands listed in the other answers are partly incorrect, as the file `TextTransform.exe` has been moved to a new directory: the `devenv` root folder, e.g.:

```
C:\Progra~1\Visual Studio 2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE
```

The command should now be updated to the following:

```
"$(DevEnvDir)TextTransform.exe" -out "$(ProjectDir)xxx.cpp" "$(ProjectDir)xxx.tt"
```

where `xxx` is the file name of yout `.tt` template file

Comment: `C:\Program Files...\Common7\IDE` is under the `DevEnvDir` environment variable in the developer console if anyone's looking.

Answer (score 0):

Having experimented with some of the above (and found them unsuitable for my specific case), I took a different approach that others may find helpful.

Rather than fight to get VS to accept a T4 template within a C++ project, I added a separate (empty) C# project to my solution.  I put my template file at the root of the solution and add a link to it from the C# project.  I #include the generated .h file from my C++ project.

I used the template to generate a version string that updates with every build.  I added the [AutoT4](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BennorMcCarthy.AutoT4) tool to VS so that the string is updated with every build of the solution.